# Get IIS User Before Impersonate And After Impersonate in ASP.NET Behind Code

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.0, impersonation

I use impersonate in my site, and I need to log each request to site, so need the username also, I think we can get this in server variables, but both `Auth_User` And `LogOn_User` return empty string. How can I get the username before impersonate and after impersonate? does any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use [HttpContext.Current.User.Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

```
WindowsIdentity wId = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsIdentity wIdb4 = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string name = wIdb4.Name;
Response.Write("Before impersonation"+name +"<br>");// <-- Writes ASPNET Account


//Till this line,code is executed in the context of worker process
WindowsImpersonationContext wIdCon = wId.Impersonate();
WindowsIdentity wIdafter = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
name = wIdafter.Name;
Response.Write("After Impersonation " + name + "<br>");// <-- writes Logged in user

//Run in the context of logged authenticated user, do your //operations that require impersonation

wIdCon.Undo();
WindowsIdentity wIdafterUndo = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
name = wIdafterUndo.Name;

Response.Write("After undo Impersonation " + name + "<br>");

OUTPUT
Before impersonation SERVER\ASPNET
After Impersonation TestAccount
After undo Impersonation SERVER\ASPNET
```